Add substring to all cells
I have this df:

I want to modify only the cells that are not empty for columns color1, ..., colorN by appending string data contained in the corresponding rows of column date. Example of output:

I use this method with openpyxl but is very slow:
for colonn in range(2,ws.max_column+1):
    #print("Elaboro colonna: " + str(colonn))
    for rig in range(2,ws.max_row+1):
        ValoreCell = str(ws.cell(rig,colonn).value)
        Valoreheader = str(ws.cell(rig,1).value)
        if ValoreCell != None and ValoreCell != " ":
            if "_" in ValoreCell:
                Valoreheader = Valoreheader.split("_")[0]
                #print("Valoreheader " + str(Valoreheader))
                Valor = ws.cell(rig,colonn).value
                ws.cell(rig,colonn).value = str(Valor) + "." + str(Valoreheader)

how can I do it in a faster way?
is there a pandas way to do it?
Edit: In the example was missing a part of the data, edited. There are empty cells, string and NaN as shown in the images.
is my first time on stackoverflow, how can i post the tabels not as images?

Please provide your input in a reproducible format (not images), also be explicit: are the empty cells empty strings or NaNs?

You can use a mask and vectorial modification:
df = df.set_index('date')

df[df.fillna('').ne('')] = (df.astype(str)
                            .add('.'+df.index.str.extract(r'_([^_]+)$', expand=False),
                                 axis=0)
                           )

Or:
mask = df.fillna('').ne('')
mask['date'] = False
df[mask] = (df.astype(str)
              .add('.'+df['date'].str.extract(r'_([^_]+)$', expand=False),
                   axis=0)
             )

Example:
# input
                    date  0  1  2
0  cas1_05.04.2024 16:40  A  B   
1  cas2_05.04.2024 16:40     C   
2  cas3_05.04.2024 17:30  D     E

# output
                    date                   0                   1                   2
0  cas1_05.04.2024 16:40  A.05.04.2024 16:40  B.05.04.2024 16:40                    
1  cas2_05.04.2024 16:40                      C.05.04.2024 16:40                    
2  cas3_05.04.2024 17:30  D.05.04.2024 17:30                      E.05.04.2024 17:30


Date is changing almost every row, is not constant

@DavideC. I see, I'll update but please provide a [mre], not images

sorry, the example was missing a part

@DavideC. have you tested if the above approach works for you? Can you edit your answer with the output of df.head(10).to_dict('list')?

You can load the data with pandas in a dataframe (df),
df['color1_new'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.color1 + "." + row.date[5:-1], axis=1)

it will generate a new column called color1_new where every element is a string composed by color1 + "." + the date field (first 5 character excluded).
Repeat for other columns and feel free to further customize it.
